# Wordpress stylesheet does not load at login page

Tags: wordpress-theming

I updated Wordpress to 4.3 version and the login page is not styled at all. At the sources the stylesheet doesn't seem to load. Is there any particular reason for this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the login page was overwriten during the update.  Are you using a standard Wordpress Theme (2012, 2013, etc.) or a custom theme.  In either case, you should paste your header text so we can see it.

Comment: I use a custom theme. I didn't make any change to the login file..I just added CSS to style.css. But it seems that the style.css doesn't load for login page at all. I load styles with the functions.php using this code: wp_enqueue_style(
  'main-style',
  get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css'
 );

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was overwritten! Unbelievable mistake! I edited a core file and forgot it..And even though you said it before I thought "No way, didn't change it". So it needs a different way to add stylesheet in the login page..the usual enqueue way doesn't work.. did it like this:                                           function my_custom_login() {
echo '';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');

Is this the only way?

Thanks for answering my noob question..